# One of Row items is not displayed in Jetpack Compose view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Here's a test composable:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun SliderInRow() {
    Row {
        Text("qwe")
        Slider(value = 0f, onValueChange = {})
        Text("wer")
    }
}
```

I want a row with a text, a slider and another text. However, the last text composable (`wer`) is missed:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Slider` is designed to take all width available, same as any view with [`Modifier.fillMaxWidth`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).fillMaxWidth(kotlin.Float)) does.

That's why he compresses the last view and makes it zero width.

The recommended way to create such a layout is to add `Modifier.weight(1f)` to the flexible view, `Slider` in you case. From its [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)):

> The parent will divide the horizontal space remaining after measuring unweighted child elements and distribute it according to this weight.

```
Row {
    Text("qwe")
    Slider(value = 0f, onValueChange = {}, modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
    Text("wer")
}
```

Comment: Hi @philip-dukhov. I'm trying with your solution but nothing is working... I'm with "androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.0-beta04". The view on the right is still invisible.

Comment: In fact. I was using RangeSlider but not Slider... With Slider it works well with weight(1F) ! But not for RangeSlider... really strange :(

Comment: @Blunderer this looks like a bug of `RangeSlider`, I've created [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210289161), star it to bring more attention. Until it's fixed, you can put `RangeSlider` in a `Box` and apply `weight` modifier to the `Box`, like `Box(Modifier.weight(1f)) { RangeSlider(...) }`